# XQuery: how to cross elements to get to the internal elements

Tags: xml, xquery

```
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<fortest>
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
</fortest>

</bookstore>
```

For the example above, if I want to get all the `<book>` elements using for statement, I need 2 for statements:

```
for $x in doc("test.xml")/xs:bookstore/book
return $x

for $x in doc("test.xml")/xs:bookstore/fortest/book
return $x
```

Could we go cross the `<fortest>` tag to get all the `<book>` elements inside `<bookstore>` using just one `for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `doc("test.xml")//book` would work. You can read it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `for $x in EEE return $x` can be simplified to `EEE`.

Second, I've no idea what the "xs:" prefix in your code is there for.

So (adapting and simplifying the answer from @har07) you can write:

```
doc("test.xml")/bookstore/(.|fortest)/book
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the other answer, you can use `//` to select `book` element located in *any level depth* within `bookstore`.

Alternatively, if you need the XQuery to work strictly on the 2 possible structures posted, you can use union operator like so :

```
for $x in doc("test.xml")/xs:bookstore/(self::xs:bookstore|fortest)/book
return $x
```